# Recursing for elements by order

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

Today in class we were given a task to 'recreate' the jQuery functionality
 (I don't know why, I guess the teacher is sadistic).

We were given the following instruction:
Using only pure javascript (not even ECMEScript 2015) create a function '$' that will receive a tag / id / class.

- If you're given only one token [ e.g $("#id)] return the suitable elements.
- If you're given more than one token [ e.g $("nav div div p")]- search hierarchically for the last token.

**Input:** $('nav div p');

**Goal:** Get all the p elements that has a div above them which has a nav above the div.

```js
if (query.split(" ").length > 1) {

  var first = query.split(" ")[0];
  var rest = query.split(" ").slice(1);
  var curr_elements;

  if (first.match(/^#.*/i)) {
    curr_elements = (document.getElementById(first.substring(1)));
  } else if (query.match(/^\..*/i)) {
    curr_elements = document.getElementsByClassName(first.substring(1));
  } else if (query.match(/^\w.*/i)) {
    curr_elements = document.getElementsByTagName(first);
  }
  curr_elements = [].slice.call(curr_elements);

  for (var e = 0; e < curr_elements.length; e++) {
    if (curr_elements[e].hasChildNodes()) {
      for (var i = 0; i < rest.length; i++) {
        var temp = rest[i];
        var children;
        if (temp.match(/^#.*/i)) {
          children = (document.getElementById(temp.substring(1)));
        } else if (temp.match(/^\..*/i)) {
          children = document.getElementsByClassName(temp.substring(1));
        } else if (temp.match(/^\w.*/i)) {
          children = document.getElementsByTagName(temp);
        }
        alert(children);
        //curr_elements += children;
      }
    }
  }

  this.elements = curr_elements;
} else {
  if (query.match(/^#.*/i)) {
    this.elements.push(document.getElementById(query.substring(1)));
  } else if (query.match(/^\..*/i)) {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByClassName(query.substring(1));
  } else if (query.match(/^\w.*/i)) {
    this.elements = document.getElementsByTagName(query);
  }

}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p id="1"></p>
</nav>

<nav>
  <div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <div>
      <p id=2></p>
    </div>
  </p>
</nav>
<nav>
  <div>
    <p id="3"></p>
    <p id="4"></p>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p id="5"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### Variables:

**query:** the first arg, is tag / id / class name.
**curr_elements:** array-to-be for temporarily storing the elements I get.
**this.elements:** the final HTMLCollection.

The part relating to single token ($("p");) works fine, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to recurse / iterate over the elements to get the paragraphs.

Hoping to get someone's idea / advice on how to continue.

Comment: The reason is for you to learn, and if you ended here asking is that the professor is doing well, as you don't know how and you are going to learn from doing it ;-)

Comment: First suggestion: press the **Run code snippet** button and look at the error. You can also do that by opening up the dev console.

Comment: Also look at the validity of the HTML. You cannot nest divs in P and Ps in Ps - you snippet is not running as a [mcve]

Comment: Interestingly you use the word "Recursing" but your code is not doing any of that - it probably should.

Comment: guys the html snipplet was just an example instead of posting the real html, I didn't pay much attention whether it works or not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fairly solid, you just are not using recursion which in this case is quite useful.

I've changed your code to use a recursive approach:

```js
function $(selector, context) {
  if (!selector) return false;
  // context should be an array of previous nodes we have found.  If it's undefined, assume the single-item array [document] as the starting context
  if (!context) context = [document];
  
  var s = selector.split(" ");
  var first = s.shift();
  var curr_elements = [], els;
  
  for (var i=0; i < context.length; i++) {
    var c = context[i];
    // make sure els gets converted into a real array of nodes
    if (first.match(/^#.*/i)) {
      els = [c.getElementById(first.substring(1))];
    } else if (first.match(/^\..*/i)) {
      els = [].slice.call(c.getElementsByClassName(first.substring(1)));
    } else if (first.match(/^\w.*/i)) {
      els = [].slice.call(c.getElementsByTagName(first));
    }
    curr_elements = curr_elements.concat(els);
  }
  
  // if there are more items in s, then curr_elements is the context in which to find them.  Otherwise, curr_elements is the array of elements we were looking for.
  if (s.length) return $(s.join(" "), curr_elements);
  
  return curr_elements;
}

var a = $(".test span");
console.log(a);
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="not_test">
  <span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span>
</div>
<p class="test">
  <span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks James, it works great!
I did notice it tends to return the same element twice in case one of the token in the query repeats itself (if the html tree is div > div > span it will and function is $(div span) it will return the same span twice).

I'll try to figure out how to cancel that, thanks again!

Comment: Mike that's true, I didn't really consider that.  You might filter out the curr_elements array for dupes.